# how long can i expect tile paint to last on a bath and vanity

Tags: tile, paint

I hope to update my bathroom by painting the bath and vanity to white from cream. How long can I expect this to last ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The longevity of any paint job depends on so many factors; it is my opinion is that this question is too broad (see the [How To Ask](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for details).

That being said, you will get the longest life if you:

- properly prepare the surfaces to be painted; that means thoroughly sanding all surfaces and perhaps acid-etching the "bath" (if by the term "bath" you mean a porcelain coated bathing tub) if recommended by the coating manufacturer. **Note**- this is the *most* important consideration, hence is listed first
- apply the paint *exactly* as directed
- use the best quality applicators
- use the highest quality paint product

The conditions the coating will be subjected to will also determine longevity, such as moisture, light, cleaning methods, human contact, etc.

Comment: When I was younger and fairly fit I got in a tub which had been refinished. It was the slipperiest surface I had ever been on--completely unusable. I was testing it because the previous user had slipped while entering the tub for a shower resulting in a badly broken humerus and other injuries. Even prepared, I could barely manage to stay on my feet. I made the surface usable by scrubbing it with abrasive scrubbing powder.

Comment: Yes, good to consider. Often the retail 2-part epoxy paints sold for this have available as an option a fine sand that can be added (in the proper proportion) to the final coat , to give some grip to the surface.